# How to compute the maximum stable rate of a flow network on producing a given quantity?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Say we have a flow network with multiple sources and a singe sink.
On each edge, we have the maximum flow rate (capacity).
On each vertex, we have the remained quantity.

Now we want to draw a given quantity to fill the sink. How to efficiently determine the maximum stable(fixed) rate we can achieve?

This is a variant of [maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).
In comparison to maximum flow problem, each vertex has a limited amount of resource(remained quantity), it reduces as it flows to the descendants. Once depleted, it cannot produce any flow. The flow from its ascendants can replenish the vertex.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Example:

> A flow network
>
> - u(1)->[2]->v(0)
>
> where we have two vertex `u` and `v` with remained quantity 1 and 0 respectively, and an edge `(u,v)` with capacity 2. To draw a total quantity of 10 to fill the sink `v`, the maximum stable flow would be 0 or unsolvable.

> A flow network
>
> - a(8)->[2]->b(0)
> - c(5)->[1]->b(0)
> - d(7)->[7]->b(0)
>
> To draw a total quantity of 20 to fill the sink `b`, the maximum stable flow would be 1.6+1+1.4 = 4.
> The flow lasts for 5 seconds, a,b and c contributes a flow of 1.6, 1 and 1.4 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your statement correctly, your problem is reducible to a maximum flow problem by adding for every vertex `u` a corresponding source vertex `s_u` and an edge between `s_u` and `u` of capacity the remained quantity of `u`. That way additional resources can flow from any vertex within the limit of their remained quantity.

Comment: Say a network u(1)->[2]->v(0), where we have two vertex u and v with quantity 1 and 0 respectively, and an edge (e,v) with capacity 2. If we want to draw a total quantity of 10, to fill the sink v, the maximum stable flow would be 0 or unsolvable. With your algorithm, the maximum stable flow would be 1.

Comment: In that case I don't understand the problem correctly, and still don't with your examples. Can you provide a clear mathematical definition, or tell us where does the problem come from to help with the intuition?